# JQuery scripts occasionally don't work

Tags: php, jquery, html, debugging

Beginner here. My site - [www.robbiedawson.com](http://www.robbiedawson.com) - occasionally fails to load any of the text in the grey footer, including numbers, and links, preventing navigation. I'm encountering this on refresh with and without cache disabled, about 1 in 20 times on wifi connection, 1 in 2 on my 4G connection, almost exclusively on the "posters" pages that have more data to load. There are no errors showing in the console. Moving my `JQuery` scripts to the footer produces this bug every time, again without errors in console.

Even placing *empty* `<script></script>` tags before the `</body>` tag causes this bug to occur every time. As does changing `$(document).ready(function()` to `$(window).on('load', function()`.

Several of these `JQuery` scripts are making use of `<?php echo json_encode($var); ?>` to work with information about the contents of folders on the server to determine the text in the footer.

I'd be interested to hear of any possible causes, fixes, or workarounds for this.

Comment: Code Base formatted

Answer (score 0):

There are errors in your HTML, including:

```
<img class="image-2 caption" src="image1.jpg" onerror="this.src='/error/derp.jpg'"></img>
```

Image tags do not have a closing tag. Also:

```
<div class="tab"id="tab-2">
```

You have to put spaces between attributes (class and id). Try cleaning up the HTML, there's a good chance that might resolve the issue.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I've now cleaned up the html and it now validates ok. Unfortunately the problem is still there. Any further ideas much appreciated.